# Save program from iPad to Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, archive

I bought some program for iPad and this program became crucial for my work - if the iPad will corrupt/+developer delete the program from AppStore I will be in great trouble.

So, my question is how can I save the program from iPad to MBP (from MBP to external HDD) to prevent any future corruptions of the program/store etc. Could I reinstall the program back to any new iPad from HDD only (if it will be unaccessible from Appstore).

Answer (score 1):

You can log into your iTunes Store account in iTunes on the Mac and download the app there. As long as you have a copy on your Mac you can always sync it to your iPad if required.

The `.ipa` file (the app) is stored in `/Users/<youruser>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications`, the name may need some guessing. You can also right-click on the app icon directly in the App view in iTunes and select "Show in Finder"

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I cannot see the program in AppStore application on Mac (the program is for iPad only), this is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Ilan The app will be in iTunes App Store, not the Mac App Store, and the downloaded ipa can be synced later.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside ok, I see the app in iTunes store, but there is no any button to download it :(

Comment: @Ilan [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrafi.jpg)

Comment: @GeorgeGarside unfortunately, I don't have any option to download, no matter what I try. How do you upload pics? I will post to show what i see

Comment: @Ilan Use the image uploader in the question editor to upload the image and get a link which you can post in a comment.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside this is what I see on mac - http://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Iky.png

Comment: @Ilan Click the app icon to go to the screen shown in my screenshot

Comment: @GeorgeGarside :) it does not change :( http://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWBk.png

Comment: @Ilan you already have the app on your computer, otherwise you won't see it on the screenshot

Comment: @patrix :) I did not download these apps to MBP. Any way, where do you think I should search for them on MBP? i'll check

Comment: @ilan they got synced automatically when you synced your iPad

Comment: @patrix is there a way to know 100% that the program was saved to mbp? while in sync i was sure this prog was skipped